# Vaadin + Spring Security. Session timeout после разлогинивания

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

Для приложения построенном на Vaadin + Spring Security пишется логика logout. Я создал SecurityService который занимается операциями login/logout а так же занимается "remember me". Итак, если я залогинюсь на одной вкладке браузера, затем открою (в этом же браузере) вторую вкладку, после этого разлогинюсь на любой из них, на оставшейся вкладке (на которой я не разлогинивился) я получаю Communication Error (когда использовать кнопки или происходит polling), или же меня выбрасывает на начальную страницу (скорее всего от heartbeat запроса). Я же ожидаю получения Session expired error:

```
public void logout() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    Optional.ofNullable( VaadinSession.getCurrent() )
.ifPresent( session -> session.close() );

}
```

also

```
session.getSession().invalidate()
```

didn't help.